# VSTO GetStorage

Tags: vsto, storage, outlook-addin

I'm working on project, which main goal is synchronization between outlook's calendar and our application's calendar. In our application, we are using custom programming language and we are *mapping outlook functions through dispatchId*.

And here comes my problem. I'm using `StorageItem` in Outlook calendar for saving some internal data, but when I try to call `GetStorage` method, from time to time it ends with Exception.

> **Exception message is "Incorrect function" (its translated from czech "Nesprávná funkce")**.

I'm calling `GetStorage` in different folders (calendars), in different data stores (.pst). When I try to call `GetStorage` method right from vsto addin, it works everytime. But calling it within our app through COM, its just pain.

I cannot induce exact behavior, it looks like it happens randomly.

**Syntax:**

```cs
  oFolder := oNS.GetFolderFromID(OFolderID,''); // ok, folder found
  if oFolder <> nil then begin
    oStorageItem := oFolder.GetStorage('Synchronization.Info', 0); // exception
    if oStorageItem.Size > 0 then
      Result := False;
  end;
```

**Example situation:**

First datastore:

- calendar called "firstCal"
- calendar called "secondCal"

Second datastore:

- calendar called "thirdCal"

Calling getStorage:

1. calling firstCal.GetStorage - Exception
2. calling secondCal.GetStorage - ok
3. calling thirdCal.GetStorage - ok

.. and other random combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution thanks to this thread http://www.delphigroups.info/2/11/941254.html.

"Delphi raises an error it is anything but S_OK (0), but VB(Visual Basic) checks if it is>0 (that's what SUCCEEDED macro/function does)."

Our custom language is based on Delphi. GetStorage function call result was 1, and we were expecting S_OK (0) if call was ok.